# For the machine element shown, locate the X, Y and Z coordinate of the center of gravity

Tags: mechanical-engineering, composite

QUESTION: [image]

My working: I had divided the body into 5 common shapes which are shown here: 
[image]

now that I'm solving for x bar, y bar, and z bar I find it difficult in finding the x, y and z directions.

see my table of working here: [image]

Comment: I cannot understand your table. :( Do you know the center of gravity of a circle?

Comment: first column is the volume calculation of the shape, the second column is the x bar or x direction of the shape, same as y and third is the x direction multiply by volume and sames as for y. 

the element had been divided into five common shapes, two rectangular, two half cylinders and one cylinder.

Comment: I will try to give inputs.

Comment: I think the only challenge here is to determine the centroid of a half circle. Am I right?

Comment: click this link and see what i had try: http://www53.zippyshare.com/v/HRgoVoQL/file.html

Answer (score 4):

Try this one. (Note: I don't know how to do tables in this site but please tabulate the data on your own.)

**Areas are:**

1. $0.75(4)(7)$
2. $\frac{\pi(2^2)}{2}(0.75)$
3. $-\pi(1.25^2)(0.75)$
4. $1(4)(2)$
5. $-\frac{\pi(1.25^2)}{2}(1)$

*Note: Negative areas as **holes** that need to be subtracted from the system.*

**X-Centroids** are:

1. $2$
2. $2$
3. $2$
4. $0.5$
5. $0.5$

**Y-Centroids** are:

1. $-0.75/2$
2. $-0.75/2$
3. $-0.75/2$
4. $2/2=1$
5. $2-\frac{4(1.25)}{3(\pi)}$

**Z-centroids** are:

1. $7/2$
2. $7+\frac{4(1.25)}{3(\pi)}$
3. $7$
4. $2$
5. $2$

You can then apply **Varignon's Theorem** to get the centroid.

Comment: I just edited. I made a mistake looking at the location of the x-axis. Y-centroids for areas 1,2, and 3 should be negative

Comment: And please understand how the values are taken. :)